# Associate file extension with Electron application

Tags: node.js, electron

When a user double clicks on a file with an extension of `cmf`, I would like to automatically launch the Electron application that I've built. I've been searching around and I've seen several mentions of the `electron-builder` but no examples of how this can be used to create this association.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at the [protocol](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/protocol) functionality. I don't have enough experience with it to understand the finer points: like which app takes precedence if multiple app register the same protocol. Some of that might be user-defined.

---

```
const { app, protocol } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

app.on('ready', () => {
  protocol.registerFileProtocol('atom', (request, callback) => {
    const url = request.url.substr(7)
    callback({ path: path.normalize(`${__dirname}/${url}`) })
  }, (error) => {
    if (error) console.error('Failed to register protocol')
  })
})
```